# How to get passwordSignupFields from Accounts.ui

Tags: meteor-accounts

I have the following code in my meteor project:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_ONLY"
  });
```

Is there a way to get the value of the passwordSignupFields property afterwards?  If so, how do I reference it?  (eg. is it Accounts.ui.passwordSignupFields or something else?  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is `Accounts.ui._options.passwordSignupFields` .